# How to get the “inflexible semantics of monad transformers” using extensible effects?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, monad-transformers, free-monad

Consider the following example.

```hs
newtype TooBig = TooBig Int deriving Show

choose :: MonadPlus m => [a] -> m a
choose = msum . map return

ex1 :: (MonadPlus m, MonadError TooBig m) => m Int
ex1 = do
    x <- choose [5,7,1]
    if x > 5
        then throwError (TooBig x)
        else return x

ex2 :: (MonadPlus m, MonadError TooBig m) => m Int
ex2 = ex1 `catchError` handler
  where
    handler (TooBig x) = if x > 7
        then throwError (TooBig x)
        else return x

ex3 :: Either TooBig [Int]
ex3 = runIdentity . runExceptT . runListT $ ex2
```

What should the value of `ex3` be? If we use MTL then the answer is `Right [7]` which makes sense because `ex1` is terminated since it throws an error, and the `handler` simply returns the pure value `return 7` which is `Right [7]`.

However, in the paper [“Extensible Effects: An Alternative to Monad Transformers” by Oleg Kiselyov, et al.](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/extensible/exteff.pdf) the authors say that this is “a surprising and undesirable result.” They expected the result to be `Right [5,7,1]` because the `handler` recovers from the exception by not re-throwing it. Essentially, they expected the `catchError` to be moved into `ex1` as follows.

```hs
newtype TooBig = TooBig Int deriving Show

choose :: MonadPlus m => [a] -> m a
choose = msum . map return

ex1 :: (MonadPlus m, MonadError TooBig m) => m Int
ex1 = do
    x <- choose [5,7,1]
    if x > 5
        then throwError (TooBig x) `catchError` handler
        else return x
  where
    handler (TooBig x) = if x > 7
        then throwError (TooBig x)
        else return x

ex3 :: Either TooBig [Int]
ex3 = runIdentity . runExceptT . runListT $ ex1
```

Indeed, this is what extensible effects do. They change the semantics of the program by moving the effect handlers closer to the effect source. For example, `local` is moved closer to `ask` and `catchError` is moved closer to `throwError`. The authors of the paper tout this as one of the advantages of extensible effects over monad transformers, claiming that monad transformers have “inflexible semantics”.

But, what if I want the result to be `Right [7]` instead of `Right [5,7,1]` for whatever reason? As shown in the examples above, monad transformers can be used to get both results. However, because extensible effects always seem to move effect handlers closer to the effect source, it seems impossible to get the result `Right [7]`.

So, the question is how to get the “inflexible semantics of monad transformers” using extensible effects? Is it possible to prevent individual effect handlers from moving closer to the effect source when using extensible effects? If not, then is this a limitation of extensible effects that needs to be addressed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm also a little confused about the nuance in those excerpts from that particular paper. I think it's more useful to take a few steps back and to explain the motivations behind the enterprise of algebraic effects, to which that paper belongs.

The MTL approach is in some sense the most obvious and general: you have an interface (or "effect"), put it in a type class and call it a day. The cost of that generality is that it is unprincipled: you don't know what happens when you combine interfaces together. This issue appears most concretely when you implement an interface: you must implement all of them simultaneously. We like to think that each interface can be implemented in isolation in a dedicated transformer, but if you have two interfaces, say `MonadPlus` and `MonadError`, implemented by transformers `ListT` and `ExceptT`, in order to compose them, you will also have to either implement `MonadError` for `ListT` or `MonadPlus` for `ExceptT`. This O(n^2) instance problem is popularly understood as "just boilerplate", but the deeper issue is that if we allow interfaces to be of any shape, there is no telling what danger could hide in that "boilerplate", if it can even be implemented at all.

We must put more structure on those interfaces. For some definition of "lift" (`lift` from `MonadTrans`), the effects we can lift uniformly through transformers are exactly the algebraic effects. (See also, [Monad Transformers and Modular Algebraic Effects, What Binds Them Together](https://www.fceia.unr.edu.ar/%7Emauro/pubs/haskell2019.pdf).)

This is not truly a restriction. While some interfaces are not algebraic in a technical sense, such as `MonadError` (because of `catch`), they can usually still be expressed within the framework of algebraic effects, just less literally. While restricting the definition of an "interface", we also gain richer ways of using them.

So I think algebraic effects are a different, more precise way of thinking about interfaces before all. As a way of thinking, it can thus be adopted without changing anything about your code, which is why comparisons tend to look at the same code twice and it is difficult to see the point without having a grasp on the surrounding context and motivations. If you think the O(n^2) instances problem is a trivial "boilerplate" problem, you already believe in the principle that interfaces ought to be composable; algebraic effects are one way of explicitly designing libraries and languages around that principle.

"Algebraic effects" are a fuzzy notion without a fixed definition. Nowadays they are most recognizable by syntax featuring a `call` and a `handle` construct (or `op`/`perform`/`throw`/`raise` and `catch`/`match`). `call` is the one construct to use interfaces and `handle` is how we implement them. The idea common to such languages is that there are equations (hence "algebraic") that provide a basic intuition of how `call` and `handle` behave in a way that's independent of the interface, notably via the interaction of `handle` with sequential composition `(>>=)`.

Semantically, the meaning of a program can be denoted by a tree of `call`s, and a `handle` is a transformation of such trees. That's why many incarnations of "algebraic effects" in Haskell start with free monads, types of trees parameterized by the type of nodes `f`:

```hs
data Free f a
  = Pure a
  | Free (f (Free f a))
```

From that point of view, the program `ex2` is a tree with three branches, with the branch labeled `7` ending in an exception:

```hs
ex2 :: Free ([] :+: Const Int) Int  -- The functor "Const e" models exceptions (the equivalent of "MonadError e")
ex2 = Free [Pure 5, Free (Const 7), Pure 1]
-- You can write this with do notation to look like the original ex2, I'd say "it's just notation".
-- NB: constructors for (:+:) omitted
```

And each of the effects `[]` and `Const Int` corresponds to some way of transforming the tree, eliminating that effect from the tree (possibly introducing others, including itself).

- "Catching" an exception corresponds to handling the `Const` effect by converting `Free (Const x)` nodes into some new tree `h x`.
- To handle the `[]` effect, one way is to compose all children of a `Free [...]` node using `(>>=)`, collecting their results in a final list. This can be seen as a generalization of depth-first search.

You get the result `[7]` or `[5,7,1]` depending on how those transformations are ordered.

Of course, there is a correspondence to the two orders of monad transformers in a MTL approach, but that intuition of programs as trees, which is generally applicable to all algebraic effects, is not as obvious when you're in the middle of implementing an instance such as `MonadError e` for `ListT`. That intuition might make sense *a posteriori*, but it is *a priori* obfuscated because type class instances are not first-class values like handlers, and monad transformers are typically expressed in terms of the final interpretation (hidden in the monad `m` they transform) instead of the initial syntax.